# Spliced LED Strips with Pre-Fab Controller

Tags: led, soldering, rgb, controller

I need 2 meters of high density LED strip for a project, but high density strips are often only sold in 1 meter increments.

I'm thinking of buying two strips -- of one meter each -- and soldering them together on their contacts end-to-end.

But I'm wondering if that would create any confusion in the pre-fab controller (the [RF Magic Controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JQFI6I2)). Specifically, the controller has a lot of predefined color patterns that start by illuminating LEDs on each end of a strip and meeting in middle...**would my spliced frankenstein strip be accurately recognized by the controller as one long strip of 2 meters**, or inaccurately as two strips of one meter (or worse)?

Thanks.

Comment: i do not understand why you are asking instead of testing?

Comment: To waste less money. I would either have to buy an low-density strip I don't need, or buy an expensive high density one, and another later if the experiment works ( = more time and money).

Comment: The protocol used by these LEDs doesn't allow for detecting the number of LEDs in the chain. The controller might be hard-coded for a certain number of LEDs, or if you're lucky it might have some sort of current sensing ability to detect it (unlikely), or it might be configurable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the behavior of **pre-built end-user modules**, and not about electronic design.

Comment: Modules are part of electronic design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For anyone coming across this question in the future:**
I ended up doing as I intended -- soldering two strips end to end (cutting one strip near the end on the metal contacts, and running small jumper wires to attach the end of this strip to the beginning of the next)!

Only difference is that I used a different controller than what I posted here -- I ended up going with the ALITOVE LED WiFi Controller SP108E, because it works with app on phone to control via bluetooth (or WiFi I guess)...and it worked!! **The ALITOVE controller had an initialization step of setting how many LEDs are in the strip, and I simply set the correct number of LEDs in the spliced-together two strips, and it recognized all of them such that patterns accurately pass over the splice like it wasn't even there!**

Thanks for help.

Comment: Glad that you solved your problem and posted an self answer (which you should accept) so that the question counts as resolved.  However this question is off topic here.  A question about designing an LED strip controller could be on topic; one about *using* one is an end-user question, not a design question.